# How to pass the scopes I need in the microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate() method

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, microsoft-teams

After creating a teams-tab-app using the vscode teams toolkit, I see that in the default auth-start.html file the script tries to extract the scopes from the URL (that was constructed by the microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate() method), however I don't see any reference in the documentation on how to pass these scopes in this method.

Does anyone know how to pass these scopes?

Comment: Could you please share the documentation you are referring to?

Comment: I might just be doing something wrong, but it's not listed in here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams.authentication.authenticateparameters?view=msteams-client-js-latest @Meghana-MSFT

Comment: Could you please share some reference doc or sample where scope is being extracted? Also please share the repro steps.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT This is just by using the default teams vscode extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamsDevApp.ms-teams-vscode-extension), exactly by the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/visual-studio-code-overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wondered about this myself when looking at a toolkit, but I haven't used it for any production systems so never bothered to look too deep. I do see that in `useTeamsFx.tsx` is where it's doing the redirect to `startLoginPageUrl`, so presumably you need to set `REACT_APP_START_LOGIN_PAGE_URL` to be the path to the `auth-start.html`, so you could set it to include a querystring as well. It needs the app Id so you'd need to set that as well, but the useTeamsFx also wants `REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID` which you'd set as well. As a result, it might make sense to store the scopes you want in your code or in an environment variable as well, and then compose the value you send to `initiateLoginEndpoint`. Basically, instead of

```
var startLoginPageUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_START_LOGIN_PAGE_URL;
...
initiateLoginEndpoint: startLoginPageUrl
...
```

you might instead make it

```
var startLoginPageUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_START_LOGIN_PAGE_URL;
var scopes = process.env.REACT_APP_SCOPES;  // <-- this is added
...
initiateLoginEndpoint: `${startLoginPageUrl}?clientId=${clientId}&scope=${scopes}`
...
```

but this is untested, so no guarantees.

On a separate but related note, in my sample project, in auth-start, it refers to a very old version of MicrosoftTeams.min.js (v 1.6, and current is 1.11). I might just have a very old Teams Toolkit, but maybe not...